# mysql count each user's number of likes ,number of tweets and number of following and followers account

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, twitter, backend

I'm building a twitter-like app using node.js for fun and I have multiple tables :

**users**: to store users' data.

**tweets**: to store tweets.

**likes**: to store what users liked what tweet.

**retweets**: to store what users retweeted what tweet.

**following**: to store what user is following other users.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `following` (
  `user_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `followed_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `date_time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`followed_id`)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `likes` (
  `user_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `tweet_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `date_time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`tweet_id`)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `retweets` (
  `user_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `tweet_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `date_time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`tweet_id`)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tweets` (
  `tweet_id` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `reply_to_tweet_id` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `reply_to_user_id` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `truncated` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `author` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `text` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `media` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `entities` json NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tweet_id`)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `user_id` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `handelname` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `account_url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `bio` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `profile_pic` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `cover_pic` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `protected` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
)
```

and I want to create a new view for the users containing there information along with how many tweets 
they did like, the number of users they follow, the number of users follow them and how many tweets they have created.
 I want this information in one table but I tried many ways and none of them worked fine for me!
what is the proper solution for such a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try below query -

```
SELECT `user_id`
      ,LI.LI_CNT no_of_tweets_liked
      ,FL.FL_CNT no_of_followers
      ,FL2.FL2_CNT no_of_followee
      ,RT.RT_CNT no_of_retweets
FROM `users` U
JOIN (SELECT `user_id`, COUNT(`tweet_id`) LI_CNT
      FROM `likes`
      GROUP BY `user_id`) LI ON U.`user_id` = LI.`user_id`
JOIN (SELECT `user_id`, COUNT(`followed_id`) FL_CNT
      FROM `following`
      GROUP BY `user_id`) FL ON U.`user_id` = FL.`user_id`
JOIN (SELECT `followed_id`, COUNT(`followed_id`) FL2_CNT
      FROM `following`
      GROUP BY `followed_id`) FL2 ON U.`user_id` = FL2.`followed_id`
JOIN (SELECT `user_id`, COUNT(`tweet_id`) RT_CNT
      FROM `retweets`
      GROUP BY `user_id`) RT ON U.`user_id` = RT.`user_id`;
```

Comment: thank you Ankit Bajpai ! it worked fine when I changed JOIN to LEFT JOIN and count asterisks instead of counting IDs.
At first, it wasn't returning anything but now accurate results are returned.
But I'm getting null values instead of 0 for some users.